# How to properly implement a monoid for a red-black tree?

Tags: haskell

Good afternoon, I am trying to write a RB Tree monoid, the code is about this:

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Node a Color (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show)

instance (Ord a) => Monoid (Tree a) where
    mempty = Leaf
    l1 `mappend` l2 = foldl (\x y ->insert y x) l1 l2


instance Foldable Tree where
   foldr _ z Leaf = z
   foldr f z (Node d _ l r) = foldr f (f d (foldr f z r)) l
   foldl _ z Leaf = z
   foldl f z (Node d _ l r) = foldl f (f (foldl f z l) d) r

...

insert :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Tree a
insert x s = makeBlack $ ins s
  where ins Leaf  = Node x Red Leaf Leaf
        ins (Node d c l r)
          | x < d  = balance d c (ins l) r
          | x == d = Node d c l r
          | x > d  = balance d c l (ins r)
        makeBlack (Node d _ l r) = Node d Black l r
```

The problem is the declaration of the monoid:

```
• Could not deduce (Semigroup (Tree a)) arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration from the context: Ord a bound by the instance declaration at src/RedBlackTree.hs:19:10-35 • 
In the instance declaration for ‘Monoid (Tree a)’ | 19 | instance (Ord a) => Monoid (Tree a) where | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I understand that in order to use `insert` the values must be comparable, but it seems that I have somehow misdirected the `(Ord a)` in the instance

*Bonus question:
I also implemented `fmap`, but didn't understand the difference from `foldMap`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `Ord` that's the problem.  If you look closely at the error message you got, it starts with "Could not deduce (Semigroup (Tree a)) arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration".  In other words, in order to have an instance of `Monoid (Tree a)`, you need to first have an instance for `Semigroup (Tree a)`.  Fortunately, this is easy to add:

```hs
instance (Ord a) => Semigroup (Tree a) where
    (<>) = mappend
```

(A perhaps more idiomatic approach would be to define `<>` in the `Semigroup` instance using the `foldl` definition you were using for `mappend`, and then in your instance for `Monoid`, simply leave out the definition of `mappend`.)

---

Bonus: The difference between `fmap` and `foldMap` is clear from their types.  For your tree, `fmap` would have the type `(a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b`, indicating that it is mapping the internal `a` values to `b` values.  On the other hand, `foldMap` would have the type `Monoid m => (a -> m) -> Tree a -> m`.  You could *choose* to call `foldMap` with `m ~ Tree b`, in which case `foldMap` becomes very similar to `fmap` (the type would be `(a -> Tree b) -> Tree a -> Tree b`, which is not quite the same as `fmap`), but you could also choose to call it with `m ~ [b]` or some other monoid. (Thanks @amalloy and @Daniel Wagner for the comments.)

Comment: Thank you! it's really hard for a beginner

Comment: If `m ~ Tree b`, then `foldMap` has the same *type* as `fmap`, but I don't think it's right to say one reduces to the other. I would expect that to mean that they are the same function, but `foldMap` may rearrange the structure of the tree while `fmap` can't.

Comment: @amalloy In fact, not even the types line up. You get `foldMap :: (a -> Tree b) -> Tree a -> Tree b` but `fmap :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Ah, of course.